# Show product titles to specific delimiter on WooCommerce category archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

My products have titles that include the delimiter `|` after which I enter some SEO keywords.

Example product title `Samsung UE55AU7172 | Smart 4K UHD 55`

Can I force WooCommerce to show the product titles up to that delimiter in **product category pages** only?

For example, the above product title in the product category page would be `Samsung UE55AU7172`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` action hook to edit the title on a product category archive page.

So you get:

```php
/**
 * Show the product title in the product loop.
 */
function action_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title() {
    // Returns true when viewing a product category archive
    if ( is_product_category() ) {  
        // Removes a function from a specified action hook.
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
        
        // Get the title
        $title = get_the_title();
        
        // String contains a specific word
        if ( strpos( $title, '|' ) !== false ) { 
            // Remove portion of a string after a certain character
            $title = substr( $title, 0, strpos( $title, '|' ) );
        }
        
        // Output
        echo '<h2 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . $title . '</h2>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 9 );
```

**OR** use this to apply it on WooCommerce archive / shop / cat pages.

```php
/**
 * Show the product title in the product loop.
 */
function action_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title() {
    // Removes a function from a specified action hook.
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
    
    // Get the title
    $title = get_the_title();
    
    // String contains a specific word
    if ( strpos( $title, '|' ) !== false ) { 
        // Remove portion of a string after a certain character
        $title = substr( $title, 0, strpos( $title, '|' ) );
    }
    
    // Output
    echo '<h2 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . $title . '</h2>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 9 );
```

Comment: My theme uses these [custom hooks](https://gist.github.com/ibndawood/12b67be2c755d4baacdbd9ddcae37d06). How could I incorporate your solution?

Comment: @BB3CPO For your theme: replace `remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );` with `remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 30 );` **AND** `add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 9 );` with `add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 29 );`

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to achieve what you want

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'remove_strings_from_title', 10 );

function remove_strings_from_title() {
    
    $title = get_the_title();
    $title = strstr($title, '|', true);
    if ($title == ""){$title = get_the_title();}
    
    
     echo '<p class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . $title . '</p>';
}
```

code goes in functions.php tested & works

Comment: This code shows 2 titles for each product. A full title and another one without the text after the delimiter for each product.

Comment: Seems like you haven't added this code remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 ); .... It will show double only if you have not removed action before adding new action. I test again & it's working fine

Comment: I did add it. Maybe it's because I'm using [this theme](https://themeforest.net/item/electro-electronics-store-woocommerce-theme/15720624)?

Comment: Hey, yes it maybe because of theme